# What does "Upgrade-Insecure-Request: 1" mean?

Tags: http

I am new to bug bounties. I want to understand cyber security first before building mobile and web apps. I am looking for bugs and decided to intercept the http traffic and ended up seeing Upgrade-Insecure-Request. Can I exploit this?

Comment: It just means the client is able to upgrade to a secure context.   `Can I exploit this?`  Not really sure how, its just a boolean that client says yes I can use secure, or it can't..

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `python`, which is one of tags you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Per Mozilla:**

The HTTP Upgrade-Insecure-Requests request header sends a signal to the server expressing the client's preference for an encrypted and authenticated response, and that it can successfully handle `the upgrade-insecure-requests` CSP directive.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade-Insecure-Requests